# DDD Application Service pode chamar outro Application Service?

Tags: ddd, application-service

Não se alguém já passou por essa situação, eu tenho application service que realiza saídas de estoque (**EstoqueService**) diretamente e tenho um application service que realiza o recebimento de vendas (**VendasService**). Mas no workflow do recebimento de uma venda (**VendasService**) eu preciso realizar saídas do estoque (**EstoqueService**).

Eu devo chamar o **EstoqueService** para realizar essa função de dentro do **VendasService**?

Ou o client (no meu caso a view) dos services deve chamar o **VendasService** para realizar o recebimento e depois **EstoqueService** para realizar a saida? Assim o client teria muito conhecimento do workflow.

Pensei em criar um outro service que encapsule esse workflow e assim o client só precisa chamar o novo service.

Seria esse um caso de comunicação entre Bounded Contexts? No meu caso não estou fazendo distinção entre contextos.

**UPDATE**

No livro do Vaughn Vernon ele faz referência a um Domain Event Handler que chama outro Application Service que modifica um segundo aggregate.

Talvez esse seja o melhor caminho, desde que eu descubra como criar uma transação nova ao invés de criar uma nested transaction. Ou executar os handlers após finalizar a primeira transação como li nesse artigo http://bartswennenhuis.nl/managing-multiple-transactions-in-one-request-3/

Comment: *"eu tenho application service que realiza saídas de estoque"* - um application service não deveria realizar nenhuma regra de negócio - ele no máximo *invoca* as regras de negócio. Um application service consumir outro application service é estranho - parece indício de que ele está fazendo coisas demais. Já um domain service consumir outro domain service é natural e não tem problema nenhum nisso.